# загрузка файлов на Github скриптом python

Tags: python, github

Мне нужно делать регулярную загрузку файлов csv в репозиторий GitHub (на виртуальной машине регулярно запускается python скрипт для обработки информации, записывает результаты в csv файлы, которые мне нужно "переложить" на GitHub). Я было начал использовать вот такой код:

```
token = 'ХХХХХХХХХХХХХХ'
g = Github(token)
repo = g.get_user().get_repo('имя репозитория') # repo name

all_files = []
contents = repo.get_contents("")

while contents:
    file_content = contents.pop(0)
    if file_content.type == "dir":
        contents.extend(repo.get_contents(file_content.path))
    else:
        file = file_content
        all_files.append(str(file).replace('ContentFile(path="','').replace('")',''))

file_names = ['список имен файлов']
for item in file_names:
    with open(f'путь к файлу/{item}.csv', 'rb') as file:
        content = file.read()


    git_file = f'{item}.csv'
    if git_file in all_files:
        contents = repo.get_contents(git_file)
        repo.update_file(contents.path, f"committing {item}.csv", content, contents.sha, branch="main")
        print(git_file + ' UPDATED')
    else:
        repo.create_file(git_file, f"committing {item}.csv", content, branch="main")
```

но как выяснилось, у этого метода ограничение на размер файла - 1Мб... а у меня файлы тяжелее :( Есть ли возможность кодом python делать push относительно тяжелых файлов на GitHub?

Comment: Так почему бы не делать обычный коммит и пуш?

Comment: Ну, не очень хочется каждые два часа заходить на сервер и делать вручную коммит и пуш :( Я надеялся, что есть какие-то библиотеки, которые могут мне помочь сделать это автоматически (я знаю про существование crontab, я сейчас имел в виду то, что можно включить в код... чтобы после окончания обработки, если она была удачной, скрипт сам отгружал файлы на GitHub)

Comment: Так сделайте коммит и пуш из скрипта.